# Java Swing: Anchor images to the corners of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using eclipse, with Google's WindowBuilder Pro Plugin, to design a swing application.  I've already built fully functional JFrames, using a group layout, with their components.  I'm now trying to add an image to the corners of all the JFrames.  When I try the drag/drop, from the WindowBuilder Pro Plugin, feature all components and the JFrame itself move and resize.

Is there a way to place these images, either programmatically or drag/drop, in the corners of my frame and anchor them there so that when the JFrame resizes the images stay in their respective corners?

Programattic code that I've tried:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("image path"));
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
label.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
add(label);
```

This works great for the upper left corner, but I can't seem to figure out how to anchor other images to the other corners.

Thanks in advanced!!!

EDIT:
I want all existing components to remain where they are and have the images embedded in the corners of the JFrame behind all existing components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an null layout and setBounds() !!! Use a proper layout manager.

For example the default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. So you can create a second JPanel that also uses a BorderLayout. Then you can add images to the WEST and EAST of the panel. Then add the panel to the NORTH of the frame.

See [How to Use Border Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information. Actually, read the entire section on layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the corners coordinates; the basic conception is to lean back on component width/height; for example :

> x,y - coordinates
>
> w,h - corner component scale

**lets calculate some corners' coordinates ...**

> left-upper-corner: x=0; y=0; w=100; h=100;
>
> right-upper-corner: x=parentComponent.width-w; y=0; w=100; h=100;
>
> right-down-corner: x=parentComponent.width-w;
>   y=parentComponent.height-h; w=100; h=100;

... so, as you can see, you may base your alg on parent component width/height for example; In your case it is code like a

```
label.getParent();
```

---

Report if that helped

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `setBounds` method you probably need to know that the location that you gave to the **label** is final location and can't be changed until you add `componentListener` to the frame and call `componentResized` method, every time you resize the frame you must set a new locations for the label(s).

However it's not  best way for this issues and I am telling you don't use this way ,hope some one else (or Expert ) **give another better answer.**

but anyway it's not possible look at this example :

```
    private JLabel lable ;
    private Icon img;
   // default constructor 
    public AnchoreImage(){

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        img = new ImageIcon(AnchoreImage.class.getClass().getResource("/path to image"));
        lable = new JLabel("text",img, JLabel.LEADING);
        lable.setBounds(getWidth()-img.getIconWidth(), 20, img.getIconWidth(),img.getIconWidth());
        add(lable);
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                lable.setLocation(getWidth()-(img.getIconWidth()+20), 20);
            }
        });
        pack();
        setSize(400,400);
        setLayout(null);
    }
```